Why did this character need to sacrifice themself to stop the Third Impact?
In Evangelion: 3.0+1.0 Thrice Upon a Time, Kensuke tells Shinji that Mr. Kaji died stopping the Third Impact.

[Shinji] Um, what happened to Mr. Kaji?
[Kensuke] He died.
Someone had to sacrifice themselves
in order to stop the Near Third Impact.
Mr. Kaji decided he'd be the one. Ms. Misato let him as well.

Transcript from Forever Dreaming
There's a brief scene later on that shows Mr. Kaji getting into a ship during the Third Impact, but the scene ends before we see what he actually does.
What did Mr. Kaji do to stop the Third Impact? Why did he need to sacrifice himself to stop it?
